# Unable to Type (Via JSDoc) Styled Component Props

Tags: typescript, styled-components, jsdoc

I'm using Visual Studio Code's [Type-Checking Javascript](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_type-checking-javascript) feature.
For those unfamiliar, this enables inferred typing, so you get many benefits of typing in VS Code, without having to write types.

Unfortunately it has issues with the template tag-based components in the Styled Components library.  If I have a component like:

```
const ProductImage = styled.div`
  background-image: url("${props => props.imagePath}");
`;
```

VS Code adds a squiggly warning line, just under `imagePath` (but not `props.`), because Typescript can't infer the type of the props argument.

As I understand it, Typescript can also [get types from JSDoc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html.), so I tried adding:

```
/**
 * @param {String} [props.imagePath]
 * @param {String} [props.alignRight]
 */
 const ProductImage = styled.div`
  background-image: url("${props => props.imagePath}");
  float: ${props => (props.alignRight ? `left` : `right`)}};
`;
```

... but it doesn't work.

I don't have a `tsconfig.js`, but to enable the JSDoc typing I tried adding the following to my `jsconfig.js`:

```
// Generate d.ts files
"declaration": true,
// This compiler run should only output d.ts files
"emitDeclarationOnly": true
```

... but it also didn't help.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to type Styled Components props?
2. If so, can you do it with JSDoc, instead of explicit TypeScript code?
3. And if so, can it be done when using VS Code's inferred use of Typescript (in Javascript files)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on [this guide](https://blog.bitsrc.io/tips-for-using-typescript-with-styled-components-e5398755997f), you need to use a generic call in order to use custom types.

In typescript it would be something like:

```
const Button = styled.TouchableOpacity<ButtonProps>`
  opacity: ${(props) => (props.primary ? 0.5 : 1)};
`;
```

Unfortunately, there's no equivalent in JSDoc, but you can use a cast.

So your code would need to be something like:

```js
const styled = require('styled-components').default;

/**
 * @typedef {{
 *   imagePath: string;
 *   alignRight: boolean;
 * }} ProductImageProps */

const ProductImage =
  /** @type {import('styled-components').ThemedStyledFunction<'div', ProductImageProps>} */
  (styled.div)`
  background-image: url("${props => props.imagePath}");
  float: ${props => (props.alignRight ? `left` : `right`)}};
`;
```

The weird looking `/** @type {SomeType} */ (expression)` construct is how casts are done in JSDoc. The parentheses are required.

Note that you will need to install [@types/styled-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/styled-components) as a dev dependency.

Note 2: I tested this using JSDoc in my local setup, however I do have a tsconfig.json file.

Comment: Thanks!  Also I just want to re-emphasize: those parentheses around `styled.div` are critical! When I copied the exact comments here into my code, but *didn't* add the parentheses, the warnings still appeared, but when I added them this solution worked (without a `tsconfig.json` ... or even a `"declaration": true` or a `"emitDeclarationOnly": true` in my `jsconfig.json` ... just `"checkJs": true` seems to be enough)!

Comment: P.S. As it happens, in this particular instance the cure wound up feeling worse than the disease (ie. I'd rather have a few squiggly lines in my code than have to add all this typing nonsense).  But I do *sincerely* appreciate this explanation, and I strongly suspect I'll be using it with other Styled Components, or possibly with other "Typescript in my Javascript" issues in the future!

Comment: It's break in Styled Components v6. the official package includes types but `ThemedStyledFunction` doesn't exist.